# Syntax error in CASE expression, unable to rectify

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want below code in my where condition:
Condition statement is like :

ONE DAY PRIOR TO RENEWAL,
Policy has the Newly Independent Discount (RAP16.DSCCD = '366' exists)
AND
AT RENEWAL,
The Newly Independent discount drops (RAP16.DSCCD = '366' dropped)

I tried below code

```
AND case when tt.ja2_effdt_t = rap01.hmedt_t - 1
   then trim(RAP16.DSCCD) = '366'
   when trim(rap01.hmedt_t) <> tt.ja2_effdt_t) 
   then trim(RAP16.DSCCD) <> '366'
           end
```

There is some syntax error in below code, But I am unable to rectify it.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh can you help me how to convert above code into AND/OR form? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause. You probalby want something like:

```
AND ((tt.ja2_effdt_t = rap01.hmedt_t - 1 AND trim(RAP16.DSCCD) = '366')
     AND
     (trim(rap01.hmedt_t) <> tt.ja2_effdt_t AND trim(RAP16.DSCCD) <> '366'))
```

Comment: I want both condition is to be satisfied simultaneously, So why do we need to use OR here? Thanks!

Comment: I'll switch to AND. (Your case expression did only take care of one condition at the time. Now you see why AND/OR is better!)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, Could you please also tell why I was having the syntax error in the CASE statement.

Comment: As @ch2019 pointed out, you have an unmatched `)` at the end of `when trim(rap01.hmedt_t) <> tt.ja2_effdt_t)`.

Comment: AND case when tt.ja2_effdt_t = rap01.hmedt_t - 1
   then trim(RAP16.DSCCD) = '366'
   when rap01.hmedt_t <> tt.ja2_effdt_t
   then trim(RAP16.DSCCD) <> '366'
           end        , If i use this still the syntax error is there and it's in line second "then trim(RAP16.DSCCD) = '366'".